# Why is this equality true (PDEs)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading a proof of a lemma in Evan's book on PDEs (Pg.126), where he makes the following assertion:

$$\max_{z}\left\{\text{Lip}(g)|z|-L(z)\right\}=\max_{w\in B(0,\text{Lip}(g))}\max_{z}\{w\cdot z-L(z)\}.$$

Here $\text{Lip}(g)$ is the Lipshitz constant for the function $g,$ $L$ is a convex function which is actually the Lagrangian and $z\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ I am not sure why this true. Perhaps someone can explain?

Comment: What is $L(z)$?

Comment: The Lagrangian.

Comment: Is there any relationship between L and  g?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing deep here. Let me denote $C:=\mathrm{Lip}(g)$. Then, obviously, 
$$
C\lvert z\rvert = \max \left\{ w\cdot z\ :\ w\in\mathbb R^n,\ |w|\le C\right\}.$$ 
Therefore 
$$
\max \{C|z|-L(z)\ :\ z\}=\max \left\{ \max_{|w|\le C}w\cdot z - L(z)\ :\ z\right\},$$ 
and the most internal "max" is independent of $z$, so you can bring $L(z)$ inside of it, yielding
$$
\max_z  \left\{\max_{|w|\le C} \{ w\cdot z - L(z)\}\right\},$$
which is what the book says.